# How to mimic manual tying in a text box in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, appium

In a native app, there is a text field which doesn't accept alphabet and special characters, only accept numbers if I enter manually, which is expected behavior.
However, When I try to use below in automation script, these letters are getting entered into the field.

element.sendKeys("a") or
element.setValue("a")

Here, my test is that , even though you trying to enter non-numeric chars, field must remain blank.

How to handle this is appium/selenium?
In another word, can we mimic manual type here? I.e. when you try to programmatically enter alphabets and special characters, these should not get enter and field should remain blank.

Note, I am using "UiAutomator2".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Robot class that is in the Package java.awt.
The "robot" class types the keyboard "like" a human:

```
robot = new Robot();
for (char c : textToType.toCharArray()) {
 int keyCode = KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(c);
 if (KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED == keyCode) {
                    logger.error("Key code not found for character '" + c + "'");
                } else {
                    try {
                        robot.keyPress(keyCode);
                        robot.delay(10);
                        robot.keyRelease(keyCode);
                        robot.delay(10);
                        }
                      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply .. however, it didn't enter anything into text box.. neither number nor alphabet. I used same code as given and just before this code, I added mobilelement.click(). Not sure if MacBook is preventing to do that or something else...

Comment: @Gopal, first you need to click on the element that you wish to enter text inside. After clicking it - use my method.